# ImageJ macro "undefined variable" issue

Tags: plugins, macros, imagej

I am trying to run the Hemispherical_2.0.txt package that I haven't seen bugs for  elsewhere but receive the "Undefined Variable in line 60" error message specifically for the code

> "circle = <circle> + getResult ( "Area" , a ) ; ".

I was expecting an output of canopy cover percentage, but keep receiving this error instead.

I haven't seen people getting errors like this for  this macro, so attempting to figure out what is going wrong. The package aids in canopy cover analysis.

Sample of code from surrounding area:

> for (a=0; a<nResults(); a++) {
> circle=circle+getResult("Area",a);
> }

Comment: Outside the loop set: circle=0;
In the loop you may write: circle+=getResult(...);

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the ImageJ-macro in question is known since long. The variable "circle" must be defined before the loop is entered. This can be done like this:

```
   circle=0;
   for ( a=0; a<nResults(); a++ )
        circle+=getResult("Area",a);
```

Comment: My answer is definitely to the point. The problem of the ImageJ-macro in question is know since long: The variable "circle" is simply undefined.

Comment: Your answer may be considered OK, it's just a heads up comment. Nevertheless your edit has negated the vote and removed your answer from the queue.